# White space between two figures

Tags: floats

I have four figures all of the same size. They are all put under each other but for some reason there is no space between the first two, but for the second two there is a white space which makes the page not look nice, as I'm using a two column page and the first two comes on the top of the first column, and the second two comes on top of the second columns but there is a white space between them.
Here is the latex code I used:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}}
\caption{4}
\label{4}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}}
\caption{4}
\label{4}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}}
\caption{4}
\label{4}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}}
\caption{4}
\label{4}
\end{figure}
```

These are my packages:

```
\documentclass[conference,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{215.9mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-9.7mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{184.3mm}
\setlength{\columnsep}{6.3mm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0mm}

\setlength{\paperheight}{279.4mm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-7.4mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{0mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\topskip}{0mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{235.2mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{12.4mm}

\setlength{\parindent}{1pc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} %AAB95
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changebar}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\hfuzz2pt % Don't bother to report over-full boxes if over-edge is < 2pt
\newlength{\defbaselineskip}
\setlength{\defbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\setlinespacing}[1]%
           {\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\doublespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}%
                           {1.5 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\singlespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{\defbaselineskip}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=1.35\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\Centering\hsize=.95\hsize\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\A}{{\cal A}}
\newcommand{\h}{{\cal H}}
\newcommand{\s}{{\cal S}}
\newcommand{\W}{{\cal W}}
\newcommand{\BH}{\mathbf B(\cal H)}
\newcommand{\KH}{\cal  K(\cal H)}
\newcommand{\Real}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\Complex}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\Field}{\mathbb F}
\newcommand{\RPlus}{[0,\infty)}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\essnorm}[1]{\norm{#1}_{\text{\rm\normalshape ess}}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\seq}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\RE}{\operatorname{Re}}
\newcommand{\IM}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\Poly}{{\cal{P}}(E)}
\newcommand{\EssD}{{\cal{D}}}
% THEOREMS ---------------------------------------------------------------
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
%
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
%
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
%

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\tempheight}
\newlength{\tempwidth}

\newcommand{\rowname}[1]% #1 = text
{\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[\tempheight][c]{#1}}}

\newcommand{\columnname}[1]% #1 = text
{\makebox[\tempwidth][c]{#1}}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642833/multiple-figure-in-latex-with-captions

Comment: @AmbikaVanchinathan I don't want to use subfloat.

Comment: hard to say (there should just be `\floatsep` space between them), but I note that the last doesn't use `[t]`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Please complete your code to make it compilable. It should show us this problem on our machine. Like it stands now, we are guessing around. I just wrapped it in `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}\begin{document}---\end{document}` and it looks just fine.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've already tried it with [t] but it still didn't work.

Comment: every question should have a small complete example that demonstrates the problem.... (replace `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}` by `\rule{2cm}{1cm}`  or whatever size demonstrates the effect. Then we can run it locally and debug.

Comment: Please post a full MWE, not just code snippets. We should be checking your problem, not guessing what packages you loaded.

Comment: What happens if you add the directive `\raggedbottom` to the preamble? Incdentally, what are you trying to achieve by encasing the `\includegraphics` instructions in curly braces?

Comment: @Mico `\raggedbottom` solved it. Could you please post this as an answer to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, LaTeX will try to "fill up" each column. If it finds no other method to do so, it will fill up the columns by inserting a noticeably large amount of whitespace between paragraphs and -- importantly in your case -- between floats.

If you are more concerned about keeping the vertical distance between floats (roughly) uniform than about filling up columns, you could insert the instruction

```
\raggedbottom
```

in the preamble.